# Append() method isn't copying the style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to copy the following within a `DIV`.

```
<ul class="pie-legend"><li><span style="background-color:#0066CC"></span>10-0-1</li><li><span style="background-color:#33CC33"></span>10-0-4</li><li><span style="background-color:#CC3399"></span>10-0-7</li></ul>
```

(All this is var legend)

I've used append method to do it.
It works fine but, It can't being able to copy its style.

I have the following jQuery and HTML code:

HTML:

```
<div id="legend"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var legend = PieChart.generateLegend();
$('#legend').append(legend);
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't being able to copy the style"? What exactly are you trying to do that isn't working (please show code), and what is happening instead of the intended result?

Comment: In var legend, specifically in `<span></span>`... It has a style... This style isn't copy when I do append in the div.

Comment: @oxguy3, I think OP expected that the `append` method would copy the `style` from the `<span>` element, but this just don't make any sense as the [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) don't say anything about copying styles.

Comment: I think the style is being preserved just fine. It looks like those span tags don't have any content in them, so you probably just can't see the styles because the span tags don't take up any space on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DEMO -> http://jsfiddle.net/4dfkr0q3/

You don't have anything inside the span tag.

Change this

`<span style="background-color:#CC3399"></span>10-0-7`

to

`<span style="background-color:#CC3399">10-0-7</span>`